# Parallax effect with collapsing toolbar not working, image in header squished

Tags: android, parallax, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout

In the blog [Design Support Library: Collapsing Toolbar Layout](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/) blog article there is a header image with nice parallax effect:

[image: app screenshot]

In [a simple test project at GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/master/MyCoordinator) I am trying to achieve similar effect - but for some reason the image is squished:

[image: app screenshot]

In the [activity_main.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/MyCoordinator/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) I have tried all possible values for the `scaleType` but the image stays distorted:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/header"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
```

What am I missing here please?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried to change to `match_parent` as Apurva suggests (thanks +1):

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/header2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
```

But this does not help - the header image is squished:

[image: app screenshot 1]

[image: app screenshot 2]

Comment: You should try writing `layout_height = wrap_content` in ImageView

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help: https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/MyCoordinator/screenshot.png

Comment: Have you seen: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml and https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/support/android/designlibdemo/CheeseDetailActivity.java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, backgrounds will stretch to fit. You should be setting the `android:src` rather than the `android:background` on your `ImageView`.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header_image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/header2"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mention that in the tutorial author uses `SquareImageView`?

He overrided `onMeasure` method:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
}
```

Class is implemented [here](https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterializeYourApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/antonioleiva/materializeyourapp/SquareImageView.java)

Comment: No, I have replaced `SquareImageView`  by `ImageView` in that app (in [activity_detail.xml](https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterializeYourApp/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml)) and it still works and the header image is not squished. In my test app it is squished - and I can't figure out, why.